# How to add synonym dictionary to mysql FULLTEXT search?

Tags: mysql, dictionary, full-text-search, synonym

That way if I search for the term "mens" the term "gentlemen" will match.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cart_product
WHERE MATCH (
product_name, product_description, product_brand, metal_type, primary_stone, product_type, product_type_sub, product_series, primary_stone_sub
)
AGAINST (
'THESAURUS "english" EXPAND SYNONYM TERM OF "gentlemen"'
)
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Is this wrong? is there somethig else I have to do with this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no syntax like this in current MySQL versions, and the only thing I see is a proposal at http://forge.mysql.com/worklog/task.php?id=2428 In current MySQL, you'll have to create your own thesaurus table & join to it.

Comment: @Wrikken thanks. Yes thats where I got the above code, I didn't realise it was just a proposal. Do you know of any tutorials that explain how to build your own using MySQL and PHP?

Comment: Hi did you get anywhere with this I'm looking for something similar